# PHP Prepared statements with DATE_FORMAT and AS

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, date-formatting, sql-date-functions

This command works:

```
SELECT `username`, DATE_FORMAT( date_register , '%d %M %Y' ) AS 'date'  FROM `client` WHERE email = 'ali@abu.com' LIMIT 1
```

but I need to do prepared statements:

```
SELECT `username`, DATE_FORMAT( date_register , '%d %M %Y' ) AS 'date'  FROM `client` WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1
```

The line above does not worked. What is the correct syntax? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read on... [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: I have read it but I don't find the correct syntax example using with `DATE_FORMAT` and `AS`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the correct syntax:

First create variable for literal date format string:

```
$date_register = '%d %M %Y';
```

and then prepare it:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT `username`, DATE_FORMAT( date_register , ? ) AS 'date'  FROM `client` WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1') or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

bind the parameter like usual:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $date_register, $email);
```

after execute and store the result; access the output as usual:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $date);
```